# How can I inject a custom factory using hk2?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, testng, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm having a hard time to work with jersey test framework.

I have a root resource.

```java
@Path("sample")
public class SampleResource {

    @GET
    @Path("path")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String readPath() {
        return String.valueOf(path);
    }

    @Inject
    private java.nio.file.Path path;
}
```

I prepared a factory providing the `path`.

```java
public class SamplePathFactory implements Factory<Path> {

    @Override
    public Path provide() {
        try {
            return Files.createTempDirectory(null);
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(final Path instance) {
        try {
            Files.delete(instance);
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

And a binder.

```java
public class SamplePathBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindFactory(SamplePathFactory.class).to(Path.class);
    }
}
```

And, finally, my test class.

```java
public class SampleResourceTest extends ContainerPerClassTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig
            = new ResourceConfig(SampleResource.class);
        resourceConfig.register(SamplePathBinder.class);
        return resourceConfig;
    }
}
```

When I tried to test, I got.

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=Path,parent=SampleResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1916953383)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AbstractBinder`s should be registered as an *instance*, not as a class. So make the change

```
resourceConfig.register(new SamplePathBinder());
```

and it should work