# How can I bind a factory to a annotation-qualified injection point?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, jersey, testng, hk2

I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29763889/330457) and got an answer how to bind a named injection point.

And I don't know how to bind a factory to a qualified injection point.

```java
class SomeResource {

    @Inject
    @Some // is a @Qualifier, of course.
    private MyType qualified;
}
```

I prepared a factory

```java
class SomeFactory extends Factory<MyType> {
}
```

And I stuck on creating a binder for that

```java
class SomeBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override protected void configure() {
        // @@?
    }
}
```

I actually want to know how to use [ServiceBindingBuilder#qualifiedBy](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/ServiceBindingBuilder.html#qualifiedBy(java.lang.annotation.Annotation)).

Comment: No the `String` type is just an example. I'm binding another type.

Comment: I need to know how to bind a factory to an annotation-qualified injection point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I need an implementation for the qualifier annotation.

```java
public class Some_
    extends AnnotationLiteral<Some>
    implements Some {
}
```

So that I can use like this.

```java
bindFactory(Someactory.class)
    .qualifiedBy(new Some_())
    .to(MyType.class);
```

I really don't understand why [ServiceBindingBuilder](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/ServiceBindingBuilder.html) doesn't have a method taking an annotation class not an instance.

Comment: Another funny thing is that if you have factory for some type X and it's bound then Jersey doesn't give a shit about actual annotation. You can use custom one or Size(min=0) for example. It just needs ANY annotation on a field/parameter to pass check on start. Later the value is injected using factory.

Comment: Also you can accept own answer if you have found the solution yourself

Comment: I could not get this solution to work, at least with Jersey 2.25.1. On startup Jersey would throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Creation of FactoryDescriptors must have Factory as a contract of the first argument. I eventually ended up creating a custom annotation as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41436316/5661065